# VB.Net SetAccessControl fails when reseting permissions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, directory, file-permissions

I need to reset the permissions on a folder that was created from my ASP.Net web forms application (this is a legacy project). I can create the folder fine, but when I try to reset the permissions on the folder that was just created, I get the error **"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."**

When I create the security rules I use this code:

```
securityRules.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\User Group", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))
```

It is encapsulated inside a function called GetSecurity(proj As Project) that returns a DirectorySecurity object.

My failing code is below. The first part of the **I**f works fine, but the **Else** part fails.

```
Dim projectPath = fullPath + "\" + finalFolder
If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(projectPath ) Then
    Dim directoryProperties As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(projectPath, GetSecurity(proj))
Else
    Dim directoryProperties As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(projectPath)
    directoryProperties.SetAccessControl(GetProposalSecurity(proj))
End If
```

I made sure to add myself to the folder in the function as this is running as IIS on my local machine. I'm also the owner of the folder on the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added code to impersonate myself inside the Else block.

https://nujakcities.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/use-vb-net-to-impersonate-a-domain-user/

It works fine. It isn't a perfect solution, but since I'm replacing the entire app with an MVC app to do the same, I'm not overly concerned.

katamarayudu, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to add the access rules to `DirectorySecurity` object of the `DirectoryInfo` ( in your case *directoryProperties*)

And then set the `DirectorySecurity` object to `SetAccessControl` of the directory info object by adding new rules.

your else statement may look like as shown below..

```
Dim directoryProperties As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\\sers\\xxxx\\")
'Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the current security settings.
Dim dSecurity As DirectorySecurity = directoryProperties.GetAccessControl()
'Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\User Group", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
'Set the new access settings.
directoryProperties.SetAccessControl(dSecurity)
```

Look into below documentation too..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_SetAccessControl_System_Security_AccessControl_DirectorySecurity_

Comment: I'm trying to completely replace the current access rules on the folder. I found that if I manually set the permissions to apply to "This Folder, sub-folders and files" I can reset the permissions with my code above. Is there a way to set the "apply to" on the access rule?

Comment: Try using "inheritanceFlags" and "propagationFlags". Set InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly. So the "FileSystemAccessRule" constructor looks like  ...... FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\User Group", FileSystemRights.FullControl,InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow)

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. I did notice that no owner is set on the directory when I look at it as a domain admin from the server. Code : FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\User Group", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow)

Comment: Did you check the domain and user group properly??

Comment: if domain is "xyz", then try "\\xyz" in windows search.... Check if anything is happening

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to IIS Express on my system not really running as me. I'm promoting this to the test server which runs as a specific AD User. I'll let you know if it work.

Comment: And also to be safe, try "\\" or @ for for "identitiy reference".   .....   . I mean 
  "DOMAIN\\User Group"           OR              @"DOMAIN\User Group"